# Explanation for a summation estimation

Tags: calculus, summation

Can somebody please tell me how the formula $s_n^*=s_n+\frac{A_{n+1}+A_n}{2}$ is derived (if possible using graphs)?

> [image: Picture]

Here
$$
s = \sum^\infty_1 f(x),\qquad s_n = \sum^\infty_n f(x) $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just from the definition of $s_n^*$ ("we can do better by using the midpoint..."):

$s_n^*$ is the *midpoint* of the interval $[s_{n}+A_{n+1},s_n+A_n]$.

Answer (score 0):

The midpoint of the interval $[a,b]$ is given by 
$$
a + \frac{b-a}{2} = \frac{a+b}{2}.
$$
You can use this formula to derive the definition for $s_{n}^{*}$.